# regex to not match if pattern is found in set

Tags: regex

Currently I'm using this pattern:

```
/{{\s*(.+?)(\s*:\s*(.+?))?\s*}}/s
```

And it's doing what I want, it's matching:

```
Stuff {{ something here }} blah blah {{ something : an more }} and so-forth.
```

What I'd like is for it to not match if it finds another "{{" inside the pattern, for example:

```
Stuff {{ this will be skipped over but {{ this : will be captured }} stuff.
```

Basically, if someone forgets a closing "}}" it will prevent the match when hitting the next "{{" and then match from there.  Currently with the second example it matches like so:

```
[0] => {{ this will be skipped over but {{ this : will be captured }}
[1] => this will be skipped over but {{ this
[2] =>  : will be captured
[3] => will be captured
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: using php's preg_replace_callback

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: What's the implementation, awk, python, c++, etc?

Comment: did you want to capture `something {} here` if the input is `Stuff {{ something {} here }}`? If yes , then try this `{{\s*((?!{{|}}).*?)(\s*:\s*((?!{{|}}).*?))?\s*}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{\s*([^{}]+?)(\s*:\s*([^{}]+?))?\s*}}
```

Try this See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/14

Comment: Yup, that does it. And that's a great site.

Comment: @phazei yes try your own regexes there.You might figure out most of the things before coming at stackoverflow :)